# Html5 content display in SAP UI5 (XML Format)

Tags: xml, html, sapui5

I am trying to display the html5 content like `<p>Example Text Goes Here</p>`. I have no idea to display this in SAP UI5.

I used the sap.ui.core.HTML. But no Use. I am using xml format based view.

Can anyone suggest me to do this.

Comment: Can you share the code for what you tried with `sap.ui.core.HTML` ?

Answer (score 0):

in Xml View html namespace is defined xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
to write any html code use it like this

```
<html:P>Example Text Goes Here</html:P>
```